# Strategies for large amount of db queries for single page request

Tags: mysql, sql, caching, memcached

For sites like IMDB ( http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000138/), LinkedIn, or Facebook, it seems like there could be a thousand queries for the loading of a single page.

Is there an upper limit on the number of queries that can be (sensibly) generated on a page request? Or is this problem solved by caching, like `memcached`? Are there other strategies that can also be employed? (I imagine on IMDB the content is for the most part static for a user's page.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no real hard limit. It will all depend on a number of factors; including the profile of your db traffic, the resources available to your db, your db architecture (replicated/distributed etc), your schema, your app design, network connectivity, your user's expectations.

The best thing to do would be to have an idea of what your page load times should be (95% of page loads should be under 0.5 seconds or whatever) and then set up some benchmarking to check whether you are hitting those targets. As long as your app is structured with a layered approach and components are well encapsulated/separated you should be able to add performance improvement strategies such as cacheing as you need to to keep your performance where it needs to be.